# How do I move a JSF bean to Spring DI using request object?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, dependency-injection

I am using JSF2.0 and looking at doing some spring security 3.2.  This is requiring me to move some  bean DI from faces to Spring 3.2.

This is what I had in before in faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>site</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.Site</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>hostName</property-name>
        <value>#{header['host']}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>LoginPasswordBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.LoginPasswordBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>site</property-name>
        <value>#{site}</value>
    </managed-property> 
</managed-bean>
```

I updated faces-config with this:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

And updated web.xml with this:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

This is what I am trying now in applicationContext.xml file but is NOT working:

```
<beans:bean id="site"
    class="mypackage.Site" scope="request">
    <beans:property name="hostName" ref="header['host']"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="LoginPasswordBean" name="LoginPasswordBean"
    class="mypackage.LoginPasswordBean"
    scope="prototype">
    <beans:property name="site" ref="site"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Any ideas on how to define the site object to get access to the request header.
 The error I get is:

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'header['host']' while
>   setting bean property 'hostName';

I have also tried these:

```
header['host'] 
request.header['host']
#{header['host']}
#{request.header['host']}
```

Comment: And why would those beans have to move to Spring? Why not simply let them be JSF managed beans?

Comment: Don't think that's possible. You can do it the other way, injecting Spring managed beans in JSF. But why let the control know about the view? That leads to bad design...